# Как ограничить в числовом диапазоне

Tags: forms, html, javascript, форма

Нужно решение такой задачи, как сделать чтобы в поле `input type="text"` можно было в вводить числа от 1 до 4. Числа 5,6 и т.д. не допустимы.

Вот еще вопрос! Если сделать кнопки повышения или понижения количества, ибо тогда не срабатывает скрипт.

Вот кнопки:

```
 <a onClick="document.getElementById('count').value++; return true;">Up</a> <a onClick="document.getElementById('count').value--; return true;">Down</a>
```

Comment: Я ответил на все ваши вопросы!

Comment: Ттогда вам надо на  http://www.free-lance.ru/

Comment: Там заломят цену большую. Ну ладно, спасибо.

Comment: Вот еще вопрос! если сделать копки повышения или понижения количества, ибо тогда не срабатывает скрипт. 

Вот кнопки
<a onClick="document.getElementById('count').value++; return true;">Up</a>
<a onClick="document.getElementById('count').value--; return true;">Down</a>

Comment: Кто поставил мне минус и зачем!!?!!

Comment: Так мне минуc за что!???

Comment: Не я. у меня репы не хватит. А вот кому это понадобидлось не пойму. Схема то рабочая

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Имя страницы</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="inp1" onKeyUp="kup(1,4,'inp1')" value="">
<input type="text" id="inp2" onKeyUp="kup(6,9,'inp2')" value="">
</body>
<script>
function kup(min,max,id){
inpt=document.getElementById(id);
val=inpt.value;
buf=new Array();
for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
    buf[i]=val[i];
} 
flag=true;
for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++){
    if(parseInt(buf[i])>max||parseInt(buf[i])<min){
        buf[i]="";
        flag=false;
    }
}
inpt.value=buf.join("");
if(!flag){alert("Допустимое значение от "+min+" до "+max+"!");}
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Нажмите на галочку рядом с ответом чтоб принять его!

Comment: Сейчас изменю ответ

Comment: Вот... поняли как работает?

Comment: Спасибо. 

А можно такую фишку реализовать. Допустим при вводе цифры 5, появлялась подсказка "Допустимое значение от 1 до 4"

PS: Вы не работали с формой formcalc для джумлы? То что я сейчас делаю, это просто я такой выход придумал. А в идеале, должно быть поле ввода количества, и при появлении в этом поле цифр с 5 до 9, должна отниматься скидка в 5% допустим.

Comment: Нет я вообще всё сам пишу не пользуюсь CMS но вот вам подсказка всплывыющяя счас изменю ответ..

Comment: А если писать форму которая будет высчитывать скидку исходя из количества, а также с формой отправки на емэйл. Можете с этим помочь, за небольшую плату. Хотя бы один пример. Дальше думаю сам.

Comment: @AubakirovAlex, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: а если разрешенный диапазон 6-10, то 10 ввести невозможно, так как будет отработка по цифре 1 и НОЛЬ уже не ввести... как тогда?